# Evaluating a model in Keras with TensorFlow is too slow to be used in loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I wanted to experiment with learning neural networks using genetic algorithms. In order to easily compare it to some other learning methods, and not to focus on writing my own implementation for neural networks I wanted to use TensorFlow with Keras. I need to rate every individual (containing neural network weights) in my population, and in order to do so, I have written some simple method:

```
def rate(self, individual, x, y):
    self.model.set_weights(individual.genotype)
    return self.model.evaluate(x, y)[1]
```

Unfortunately every call takes over 2 seconds, even on simplest neural networks with one hidden neuron. I even tried to disable GPU, but it takes the same time on CPU. Is there some way to speed it up?

Comment: Try using line_profiler to see what takes the most time. It could be that set weights is slow

Comment: I've checked that it is not the problem of set_weights

<built-in method _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.TFE_Py_Execute> 3752 1520 1520
<method '_numpy' of 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' objects> 11254 1142 1142
<built-in method _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.TFE_NewContext> 1 471 471
<built-in method _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.TFE_Py_FastPathExecute> 80 332 332
get_data 2091 322 282

Comment: If you used line_profiler I would have understood it better. From the lines you posted I see no correlation to what it could be. Both lines use tensorflow. The problem could also be because of the size of x and y. I think it would also be better if you provided more of the other code. The loop itself and the definition of the model with one hidden neuron.